# What is the Best Options available to Send bulk emails using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, send-email, bulk

I have the requirement where I need to send 120K emails to external users.

The mapping of the users and templates will be stored in the SharePoint List.

I already checked few limitations like Send Email V2 can send 900 emails per minute and Exchange online can send 10000 emails per 24 hours.

What are other good options available to send bulk emails? I am okay with the custom code as well if that serves the purpose.

Comment: To overcome the Send Email V2 with one account, you can use multiple accounts to send the email. Keep the record of the count at somewhere in list and once it reach to limit you can use another account to send email. You can always use send email action with different accounts in ms flows.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to send using the “Send an HTTP request to SharePoint” action.
Here you have the ability to control the sender name (no e-mail address) by using different sites as the sender.

Screenshot for reference -

[image]

```
Site Address: URL of the site you want to send the email from.
Method: POST
Uri: _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
Headers
        accept: application/json;odata=nometadata
        content-type: application/json;odata=nometadata
Body:
    {
        'properties': {
            'To': ['someoneexternal@domain.com','externaluser@domain.com'],
            'Body': '<b>Text</b><br/>Email!',
            'Subject': 'E-mail using Flow via SharePoint'
        }
}
```

Keep sending them e-mails. Please let me know if you have more questions.